# Let N be the number of ordered pairs $(a,b)$ of natural numbers such that $a <b$ and the H.M of $a$ and $b$ is $2010$. Then last digit of N is?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Let N be the number of ordered pairs $(a,b)$ of natural numbers such that $a <b$ and the H.M (Harmonic Mean ) of $a$ and $b$ is $2010$. Then last digit of N is

We have  $$\frac{2ab}{a+b}=2010$$
which imply $$ b=\frac{1005 \ a}{a-1005}$$
where $ 1005 < a <2010$. Given relation have solution  corresponding to $a= 1006,1008,1010,1014$ and may be more such values of $a$

But How to find how many such solutions are there . Any Hint....

Comment: Hint: let $c=a-1005$ so $b=\frac{1005^2}{c}+1005$

Comment: i think N is $13$ .$c$ is factor of $1005^2$ and less than $1005$. so there will be 13 such choices for $c$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My hint in comments:

> Let $c=a−1005$ so $b=\frac{1005^2}c+1005$

Your response:

> I think $N$ is $13$. $c$ is a factor of $1005^2$ and less than $1005$. So there will be $13$ such choices for $c$

Indeed $13$ is correct.

$1005=3\times5\times 67$ so $1005^2$ has $3^{2+1}=27$ factors of which $13$ are less than $1005$, $1$ is $1005$, and $13$ are greater than $1005$.

The $13$ possibilities are in fact

```
    c   a       b   
    1 1006 1011030
    3 1008  337680
    5 1010  203010
    9 1014  113230
   15 1020   68340
   25 1030   41406
   45 1050   23450
   67 1072   16080
   75 1080   14472
  201 1206    6030
  225 1230    5494
  335 1340    4020
  603 1608    2680
```